# SQL: multiple group by in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mariadb

I have data like this:

```
ID             NR             TYPE 
-------------- -------------- ---------------
01             44             A          
01             66             B          
02             77             A
02             53             B
```

I need one query for this:

- Group by ID = AVG NR
- Group by ID + HAVING TYPE A = AVG NR A
- Group by ID + HAVING TYPE B = AVG NR B

I think the request should contains a group by on Sequence, but I can't manage to make it work

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use conditional aggregation

```
select 
   id, 
   avg(case when type='A' then NR end) as 'AVG(NR A)' ,
   avg(case when type='B' then NR end) as 'AVG(NR B)',
   avg(case when type in ('A','B') then NR end) as 'AVG(NR)'
from tablename
group by id
```